# Application pool asdf has been disabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> ...Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool.

I pulled down an old VS 2010 solution out of TFS and attempted to run it.   (After working in VS2012 now for a year.)  For some reason it refuses to F5 start and debug the project with the following message:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server.

Digging in the system section of the even viewer I found this message:

> Application pool asdf has been disabled.  Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool.

Every time that I debug the app it causes the app pool to stop.

Another team member who has not installed vs 2012 can fetch the same code from TFS and run it w/o any issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your app pool run under a different identity than the default one? If so, the user might be disabled, password expired etc.